# Shade area under and above the curve function in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2

I have a function and its domain of this function is (-100, 100)

> `fun.1 <- function(x) (-100*x)/(x+100)`

Here is my code how I draw a function.

> `ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-50,50)), mapping = aes(x=x)) +
>        stat_function(fun = fun.1, color = "black", size = 1)`

I would like to shade the area under the curve of this function in "red" color and above this function in "green" color. Can anyone have an idea how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to create a data frame of x and y first using your function, rather than passing your function through `ggplot2`.

```
x <- -50:50
y <- fun.1(x)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

The plotting can be done via 2 `geom_ribbon` objects (one above and one below), which can be used to fill an area (`geom_area` is a special case of `geom_ribbon`), and we specify `ymin` and `ymax` for both.  The bottom specifies `ymax=y` and `ymin=-Inf` and the top specifies `ymax=Inf` and `ymin=y`.  Finally, since `df$y` changes along `df$x`, we should ensure that any arguments referencing `y` are contained in `aes()`.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + theme_minimal() +
  geom_line(size=1) +
  geom_ribbon(ymin=-Inf, aes(ymax=y), fill='red', alpha=0.2) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=y), ymax=Inf, fill='green', alpha=0.2)
```

[image]